# Difference between Authorization: Bearer <token> and Authorization: JWT <token>?

Tags: jwt, http-headers

I've seen both `Authorization: Bearer <token>` and `Authorization: JWT <token>` when making HTTP requests using the Authorization header. What is the difference between Bearer and JWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't really much of a difference between the two, or any other schema you might come across being used in the header.

`Authorization: Bearer <token>` is just a standard way of passing around JWT tokens between the client and the server.

if you've written server-side code, you'll notice that you're the one placing the logic to split and extract the token from the header.

So, if you're designing both the server and the client, you can send in any key-value pair you wish to, just that they should match both sides.

You can see JWT [docs](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for more information. They mention using the Bearer schema as a standard way.